# Android: How to refresh background after a fixed time interval?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am a newbie in android development. I am developing an application in which I need to update the data at every 15 mins. And If an activity is running and at the same time, data is updated by backend then the activity should also be updated, and if the application is closed a notification should be displayed.

I am using retrofit for consuming the backend Apis. Is there any timer function is available for hitting API periodically using retrofit?

As I googled my problem I found that it can be done by AlarmManager with BroadcastReceiver or firebase jobDispatcher, I'll be glad to know if there are more ways.

What is the best and easiest approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimerTask class like this :

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
       //Hit your api from here
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 15000);
```

To cancel this simply call:

```
if (timer!=null){
    timer.cancel();
    timerTask.cancel();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to implement periodically update with Retrofit2. I am using Retrofit2 and RxJava2. Not sure if it is the simplest way to do it. At least, it works for me.

First, create the Retrofit service and then get the observable for your data.

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("YOUR_BASE_URL")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    MyRetrofitService request = retrofit.create(MyRetrofiService.class);

    Observable<MyData> myDataObservable = request.getMyData();
```

Second, create the observer for handling your data observable.

```
    observer = new DisposableObserver<MyData>() {

        @Override
        public void onNext(MyData myData) {
            // do your work here: handle your data, update UI, ..., etc.
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");
        }
    };
```

Now, create another observable to do the periodic update. It is an observable repeating every `x` second. The key is to map the periodic observable to your data observable, by using `flapMap()`.

```
    Observable.interval(x, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(new Function<Long, Observable<MyData>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<MyData> apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    return myDataObservable;
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
```

The last step is to clean up your data observable in your `onDestroy()` by calling `observer.dispose()`.